# Cucumber/Capybara returning 'Not Found' page after a redirect

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, capybara

first, sorry for the bad english.

I have a test that submit a login form. 
after redirect, when I test for a message 'successfully logged...' 
then my page.body is

`'<h1>Not Found</h1>'`

but this works perfectly on browser manual test.

what should I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds likely that one of your steps is redirecting in a way that you do not expect.

1. Check your before filters on the controller and application_controller to determine whether a login/I18n filter is redirecting your page.
2. If you have the launchy gem installed, you can also add the following to your steps:

   ```
   And show me the page
   ```

   Which will fire-up a browser with what capybara is actually looking at, which is useful for sanity checking your steps.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Tests run under their own clean copy of the database. Make sure you've set it up first using `rake db:test:prepare`, and that you're creating all the data you need for your tests as part of the feature. (I.e. `Given there is a user named "Joe"...`)